# Is it okay to disable a radio button in a group of 2?

Tags: forms, radio-buttons, disable

I have an option menu where one of the options is a simple group of 2 radio buttons:

[image]

Now in certain conditions, the 2nd option is not available, but i was wondering if it's okay to simply disable a radiobutton if there are only 2 options available:

[image]

Or should i just hide the entire radiobutton group in this scenario?

Comment: I just realized that the amount doesn't really matter. If i have a radiobutton group of 3, or 4, or 5, or 100 and all the other options are disabled until only 1 options is left, you have the same situation.

Comment: The answer is probably the same as the more generic "disable or hide" question that keeps cropping up. _Generally_ (there are always exceptions), if something is not available for reasons the user has no control over (how something is licensed; unlikely-to-change user-permissions) and therefore never likely to be able to use then you hide inapplicable options; if an option is unavailable because _at the moment_ they (or the system) don't meet certain requirements (but there's a reasonable chance they _could_ be met), then disable.

Answer (score 1):

In this condition if no other option is available to the user, you don't have to ask the question at all. It becomes an automatic attribute of the system. The user cannot change it or act on it in any way. It becomes a statement of fact somewhere on the interface.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the content of the options. If it is necessary, that the user sees option1 only for informational reasons you should not hide the option when option 2 is not available. But to show options when actually there is only one option seems strange to me an might be frustrating if the reason for the disabled option 2 is not obvious. In this case i would show an informational text rather the an radiogroup with only one option.

If it is the case that option 1 has no informational value to the user, I would hide the whole radiogroup.

There is another problem. What if the user does not fill out your form in the meant order an chooses option 2 and after that fills in the condition changing value? You would have to change option 2 into option 1 which is confusing. Both mentioned solutions will resolve this problem.

Comment: Sorry, i did mean hide the entire radio group and not just "option 2".

Comment: Yes I understand that. But a radiogroup with only one option (the other one is disabled) seems still strange...